# Why do unidentified items seem to solely exist in roguelikes?

Tags: game-mechanics, random, roguelikes

Playing a variety of games I noticed that some concepts are "trapped" in the realm of roguelikes. One of the most intriguing game-play elements in roguelikes is the unidentified item. The unidentified item can be used at any time adding another layer of randomness and chance to the game-play. I think the reason this element cannot co-exist with a saving mechanic is that you could save, use the item and then load if you are unhappy with the results. I am still puzzled if this mechanic is overlooked and it could possibly be successfully incorporated into some modern games? If you do know of examples where it is being used, please share.

Comment: IMO this is really one of those things that just doesn't really fit anywhere else. Roguelikes have it because it's been a staple of the genre for so long, but other games wouldn't really benefit from such a system. Even other RPGs such as Borderlands wouldn't see fit for unids in their system.

Comment: These types of questions are primarily opinion based. There's no definitive answers to "why does X *seem* to Y?". Since it can *seem* different to each person, and it's not necessarily a fact.

Comment: Well, one reason is that you could save and load in a game with a saving mechanic. Though even in MMORPGs where you cannot save or load it appears these game mechanic is rare.

Comment: I *think* "realms od arcania" or what it was called had unidentifieds, and eye of the beholder also. both games from the 90ties. Maybe ask on arqade if this is even true.